# Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hiber nate/cfg/Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jar, cmd, sessionfactory

I created a project in Eclipse and executed it succesfuly (*It's a normal project, without Maven or Beans, really simple*), I created a .jar with the project and tried to execute it but it throws the following error:

```
C:\Documents\wrapper-windows-x86-64-3.5.19-st\bin>java -cp QuoteHandler.jar stoc
k.view.Main
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hiber
nate/cfg/Configuration
Exception in thread "Quotes" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at stock.controller.HollidayController.<clinit>(HollidayController.java:
25)
        at stock.view.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:57)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
        at stock.controller.HollidayController.<clinit>(HollidayController.java:
22)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

**The .classpath file of the project has:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar" sourcepath="lib/hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.10.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org.springframework.beans_3.1.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org.springframework.web_3.1.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/org.springframework.context_3.1.4.RELEASE.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/joda-time-2.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

**Checking on the Internet I modify the %CLASSPATH% variable to:**

```
CLASSPATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\c3p0-0.9.1.jar
```

All the References are well configured in the Build Path of the project and it works, but when I'm executing the .jar it doesn't work (All the references are included in the jar). What am I missing?

Comment: What is the java version you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following option from Eclipse:

1. File->Export
2. From the Wizard select Java->Runnable JAR file
3. Click Next
4. Select Launch Configuration: Select the class with main() method, if it is not available here then try to run your program once in eclipse
5. Export Destination: Select full path for your jar file
6. Library Handling: Select third one "Copy required lib..."
7. click on finish

Go to command prompt and change the dir to exported jar file and type
java -jar <exported_jar>.jar

One note:
In java for classpath lib/* does not resolve to all jars in directory, you have to type each and every jar entry manually.

Comment: Good, then you can examine classpath entries inside jar file. Open jar file with winrar (winzip), go to META-INF directory and view MANIFEST.MF file.

Answer (score 3):

when you specifically specify the class path when you run your program with `-cp` you override the default CLASSPATH os variable.

So you need to either specify all the needed classes/jars as a list in `-cp`, or you need to modify your CLASSPATH to have the directory of your jar. This question, [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath), describes setting multiple classpath elements.

Comment: I used this java -cp "lib/*;QuoteHandler.jar" stock.view.Mainand shows the same error, I even create a folder in C named C:\classes and put it the Classpath variable as C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\classes, and nothing.

Comment: The only reason for the above not to work is if you are in the wrong directory when you call `java -cp` or the files aren't where you think they are.  Just make sure you are standing in a folder that has both QuoteHandler.jar and a lib folder with all the jars you need when you run the command

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to launch the program using command-line, the .classpath is file is for the eclipse project to maintain the list of jars pertaining to that project and has nothing to do with running the same code from command line, that's why you get the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

Looking at the .classpath file, I think you project structure is like:

```
Proj
|
|---src
|
|---lib
```

So in order to run the code you can do,

For windows:

```
java -cp lib/*;/path/to/your/jar/QuoteHandler.jar stock.view.Main
```

For UNIX:

```
java -cp lib/*:/path/to/your/jar/QuoteHandler.jar stock.view.Main
```

Few things to note here:
-cp argument is ignored if the -jar option is used.

```
1. So you have two options, modify the manifest file to include the classpath variables
2. Add this jar too in classpath along with other jars as mentioned above, and run the main class.
```

Also, using -cp will basically override the values of Environment Variable for that session.
Next time again if you try the program again without -cp switch, default value (set in environment variable) of CLASSPATH will be picked.

**UPDATE**
If you are using this command:

java -cp lib/*;QuoteHandler.jar stock.view.Main

```
1. Remove quotes they add no value
2. If I look at the command above it means that, you layout is something like:

 somefolder
 |
 |----QuoteHandler.jar
 |
 |----lib
 |    |
 |    |--- antlr-2.7.7.jar
 |    |--- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
 |    |--- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
 |    |--- hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar
 |    |---...and so on (NO SUBDIRECTORIES)
```

Is it the same structure you are having here?

Comment: I used this `java -cp "lib/*;QuoteHandler.jar" stock.view.Main`and shows the same error, I even create a folder in C named C:\classes and put it the Classpath variable as `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib;C:\classes`, and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in comments of using wildcards.The wildcards only work on [JDK 6 onward](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) . So if you JDK version is lesser than that, it might not work (*and the way around it to add all the jars in path*).

Comment: If you look at his classpath he is using jre7, so he should be good here